# SharePoint microfeed cant be migrated?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, powershell

I just used a 3rd party software to migrate Project sites data from 1 SharePoint site to another.
Worked like a charm except for the microfeed.
The tool doesn't support migration of microfeed.
Anybody know of a way to migrate the Microfeed??

SPDesigner wizardry?? PowerShell script?? anything?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am trying to migrate microfeed too..

Comment: @Aslan Microfeed cant be mirgated. So we had to do it all manually. we did howerer fiddle with PowerShell for a bit before we decided that it was much easier to migrate manually.

Comment: How did you migrate it manually?